# Allowing a guest user to run a script with elevated privileges

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, permissions, visudo

Using ubuntu 16.04LTS

I am trying to allow a guest user who does not have sudo powers to reload nginx whenever they need to by executing a simple script:

```
#!/bin/sh
nginx -s reload
```

which has permissions `-r-xr-xr-x`

and allowing them to do that with adding a line in the sudoers file:

```
root  ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
guest ALL=NOPASSWD: /path/to/script.sh
```

This still gives permission denied errors.

```
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open()   "/usr/local/nginx/logs/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
```

I don't want to give my guest users sudo permissions, but in order to reload nginx I usually need to use `sudo nginx -s reload`

Edit: Solved my issue - I was overthinking the problem by trying to run the commands my guest users needed via a script. Also not really getting how /etc/sudoers worked. This video helped a lot: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YSSIm0g00m4

As root I made a sudoers.d file, `visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/guests`, to correctly give my guests sudo powers over nginx and nginx alone:

```
Cmnd_Alias NGINX = /usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx
Cmnd_Alias GUESTS_CMND = NGINX
%guests ALL=GUESTS_CMND
```

Comment: More of a [ubuntu.se] or [sf] question than a programming one - voted to move.

Comment: Have you tried to setuid to root?

Comment: And how do guest run this script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in my edit - I was overthinking the problem by trying to run the commands my guest users needed via a script. Also not really getting how /etc/sudoers worked. This video helped a lot: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YSSIm0g00m4

As root I made a sudoers.d file, `visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/guests`, to correctly give my guests sudo powers over nginx and nginx alone:

```
Cmnd_Alias NGINX = /usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx
Cmnd_Alias GUESTS_CMND = NGINX
%guests ALL=GUESTS_CMND
```